# Read and display two button values with a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

*-I'm a beginner
-I have tried using chatGTP,
-I dont have any clue on what to search for on this site

The display value for Element 1 is the .price.buy value of 44,93 yet the display value for Element 2 is "Hello"...*

**Element 1:**
button type="button" class="price buy ng-tns-c232-17 u-semi-bold ng-trigger ng-trigger-price        ng-animating" disabled="" style=""> 44,93  *

**Element 2:**
button type="button" class="price sell ng-tns-c232-17 u-semi-bold ng-trigger ng-trigger-price" disabled="" style="font-size: 1em;"> 44,95  *

**Code for Element 1:**

```
const buttonBuy = document.querySelector('button.price.buy');
const buyPriceElement = document.querySelector('.buy.price');

function getPriceBuy() {
  if (buyPriceElement) {
    const priceBuy = buyPriceElement.textContent.trim();
    document.getElementById('priceBuy').textContent = priceBuy;
  } else {
    console.log('GetPriceBuy Element not found.');
  }
}

function getCurrentBuyingPrice() {
  if (buyPriceElement) {
    const buyPrice = parseFloat(buyPriceElement.textContent.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(',',     '.'));
    return buyPrice || 0;
  } else {
    console.error('getCurrentBuyingPrice element not found.');
    return 0;
   }
}
```

**Code for Element 2:**

```
const buttonSell = document.querySelector('button.price.sell');
const sellPriceElement = document.querySelector('.price.sell');

 function getPriceSell() {
  if (sellPriceElement) {
    const priceSell = sellPriceElement.textContent.trim();
    document.getElementById('priceSell').textContent = priceSell;
  } else {
    console.log('GetPriceSell Element not found.');
  }
}

function getCurrentSellingPrice() {
  if (sellPriceElement) {
    const sellPrice = parseFloat(sellPriceElement.textContent.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(',',   '.'));
    return sellPrice || 0;
  } else {
    console.error('getCurrentSellingPrice element not found.');
    return 0;
  }
}
```

**HTML:**
td width=100px>Hello
td width=100px>Hello

I'm trying to collect the buy and sell price of two buttons and I have been trying with it off and on for three-four weeks and it's enough of a frustration that I have to ask for help.